# deleting listview in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

hi i had a problem deleting items in listview on android, im using xamarin android, i have a custom row that has delete button, but when i click on it, deleting the last item not the selected item.

here is my code

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Button btnDelete;
        var item = _items[position];
        var view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = _content.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomRow, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PostTitle).Text = item.PostTitle;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PostMessage).Text = item.PostMessage;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PostDate).Text = item.PostDate;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.AuthorName).Text = item.AuthorName;
            view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.PostAvatar).SetImageResource(item.ImageResourceId);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Date_Read).Text = item.DateRead;
            btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDelete);
            btnDelete.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var delPos = (int) (((Button) sender).GetTag(Resource.Id.btnDelete));
                _items.RemoveAt(delPos);
                NotifyDataSetChanged();
            };
        }
        else
        {
            btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDelete);

            btnDelete.SetTag(Resource.Id.btnDelete, position);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

or can u tell me guys how to get the id of the selected row in listview, i think that is the problem.

```
btnDelete.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var delPos = (int) (((Button) sender).GetTag(Resource.Id.btnDelete));
                _items.RemoveAt(delPos);
                NotifyDataSetChanged();
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solve it by just putting this line of code

```
view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PostTitle).Text = item.PostTitle;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PostMessage).Text = item.PostMessage;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PostDate).Text = item.PostDate;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.AuthorName).Text = item.AuthorName;
        view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.PostAvatar).SetImageResource(item.ImageResourceId);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Date_Read).Text = item.DateRead;
```

outside the if statement `if(view == null`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you would have to move the tag set outside of the if-else. From:

```
    else
    {
        btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDelete);

        btnDelete.SetTag(Resource.Id.btnDelete, position);
    }
```

to:

```
    else
    {
        btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDelete);
    }

    btnDelete.SetTag(Resource.Id.btnDelete, position);
```

Also, try to change the Tag to this:

```
// to set
btnDelete.Tag = position;

// to retrieve
var position = (int)((sender as Button).Tag);
```

Comment: tnx for the reply, i already do that but same output, it deleting the last item not the current

Comment: Can you try the Tag setter/getter if it makes a difference?

Comment: How? , i also notice that when i add button on my custom row , i cannot click it anymore.

Comment: i mean i cannot click the listview anymore, is there any implementation of deleting items in listview without adding buttons?, like adding checkboxes to select the item u want to delete then press a icon or whatever to trigger the delete action.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to take the code in the else scope and move it outside of the else scope. Because in the current form if it's the first time that view is showed, that view won't have a tag.

```
else
{
    btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDelete);
    btnDelete.SetTag(Resource.Id.btnDelete, position);
}
```

To:

```
btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDelete);
btnDelete.SetTag(Resource.Id.btnDelete, position);
```

After that I recommend putting breakpoint to your code where you set and get the position to check if its setting and getting the position correct. You can find the error from there.

Also to make your list clickable too, you need to add this code to your xml, to the viewgroup that holds the list item:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

I created my own project and tested this and it works.

Comment: thank for the answer, i notice when i put the break point it gives the exact position but not deleting the right row. what is wrong?  `_items.RemoveAt(position);
                    NotifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: So it was deleting the correct row but it wasn't updating the listview properly because everything was inside if (view == null) scope